# How should I connect a switch as the load on a GFCI outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, gfci

I am running a GFCI from breaker to line side. White, ground, black. Then I want to add a switch and another receptacle with white, black and ground. Here where I'm not sure. Do I but a black and white on load and run black to the switch?

Comment: Is the switch supposed to turn the GFCI outlet on and off or does it control a light?

Comment: Its just for the other receptical

Comment: There's nothing special about wiring up receptacles on the load side of a GFCI. Just follow your color pattern; presumably black is hot, white is neutral, and bare or green is ground. If you don't know how to wire a switch then say so.

Comment: I know my main line goes to line on gfi ,  and i know the other receptical wires  i want to make sure how its all tied together

Comment: The stuff you wish to protect goes on the load side of the GFCI receptacle.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Comment: Study the first diagram at https://www.buildmyowncabin.com/electrical/wiring-multiple-gfci-outlets.html. It sounds like you might maybe want to call a professional.

Comment: I want to hook up a gfi from breaker.  Then from there i want to add a switch that just controls the other recpitcal i want to be able to switch on /off lights will be pluged in to that. How is all that wired  sorry for the confusion

Comment: That drawing was good but after the gfi needs to be a switch then the other receptcal

Comment: "a switch that just controls the other receptacle" Do you want one plug on the GFCI outlet to be always hot and the other to be switched, or is "the other receptacle" a totally different pair of outlets located at a different box? If it's the former option, you cannot do that with a GFCI outlet. If it's the latter option, that's simple. Please [edit] your question to indicate which option you're after. Maybe include a rough sketch of what you're after if you can't find the right words.

Comment: If you need a switched outlet, then say so. See https://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/switched-outlet-wiring-diagrams

Comment: Yes i want the switch to only control  the other recep.

Comment: I am new to this site im not sure how it all works and monkeyzeus im sorry if my wordage isnt correct. Just asking for help and no need to be rude

Comment: I would do a drawing but dont know how to on here

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude but you've elaborated on your actions without stating an end-goal. Anyways, study https://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/switched-outlet-wiring-diagrams a bit more and note that the blue "source" in the image can be perceived as your GFCI outlet.

Comment: This should have been an edit to clarify your original question instead of a whole new one. That would have been easier. Please edit that other question and include details about why the answer already provided there doesn't address the problem you're having.

Comment: Why do you even want to protect the switched thing?  Is it a receptacle? Is it a light or fan inside a shower or in a pool or hot tub area?  If you don't want/need to protect the switched thing, real easy - attach *absolutely nothing* to Load, and attach the additional wires to LINE just like on a normal outlet.  How do you put 2 wires on 1 screw? Read the GFCI instructions, required anyway per NEC 110.3.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I generally agree. But with current code, that would also include not just the traditional wet areas, but also: unfinished basement, garage, outside, etc. On the other hand, if the goal is really only a *light*, hard-wire it, skip the receptacle, and yes connect it to LINE rather than LOAD.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you want to split a duplex GFCI/receptacle so that one receptacle is switched and the other is always hot, *you can't do that*. The solution in that case is to follow the directions below except use a 2-gang box and put both the GFCI/receptacle and the plain (but switched) receptacle in the same big box. Which will give you an extra 2 receptacles (2 unswitched, 2 switched, 4 total) but nobody ever complained about extra receptacles.

1. From breaker, hot/black and neutral/white to *line* side of GFCI/receptacle. Ground to box if metal or to receptacle. If metal box and receptacle says "self grounding" then you don't need to wire ground directly to receptacle.
2. Test GFCI/receptacle - TEST/RESET, plug in a device (light, fan, radio, whatever) and make sure it works and that the TEST button makes it stop and the RESET button makes it work again. If you have a 3-light tester with GFCI function, use that to test as well.
3. From GFCI/receptacle *load* side (the part originally covered in warning tape), connect hot/black and neutral/white and run them to the switch box.
4. In the switch box, hot/black to switch, neutral/white to neutral/white of cable going to the switched receptacle, switched hot/black to black of cable going to the switched receptacle. All grounds together and to the metal box (if you use one, as you should). If the switch needs neutral (smart switch, timer, etc.) then add a pigtail from the two neutral/white wires to the neutral connection on the switch.
5. In the switched receptacle box, switched hot/black to the hot side and neutral/white to the neutral side. Same deal with ground - to the box if metal, to the receptacle if not metal, use a good receptacle marked self-grounding and a metal box to make your life easier.